# Opposite of reflection coefficient

Tags: transmission-line, math-notation, reflection-coefficient

The reflection coefficient (in circuits, for example) is generally given the symbol Gamma (\$\Gamma\$). What is the symbol given for the pass or transmission coefficient \$1-\Gamma\$?

I've usually just seen it written out in terms of \$\Gamma\$ but I'm trying to be more concise in my notation.

Comment: the more obvious notation is to use the scattering matrix subscripts, \$s_{21}\$ forward  output to port  2

Answer (score 1):

Variously:

$$
\begin{aligned}
Reflection\ coefficient&=R,\ \ \Gamma\\\\
Transmission\ coefficient&=Τ,\ \ τ\\\\
Absorption\ coefficient&=K,\ \ \alpha,\ \ \varepsilon,\ \ \mu
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I'm working with optical couplers which generally already use \$\tau\$, but 'T' may work as well.